# Create cloud watch for monitoring EC2 RAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ram, cloudwatch

I always wonder why amazon has not provided cloud watch to monitor EC2 RAM , if they are able to do it for CPU? I understand that Amazon does not have visibility into the guest O/s, whatever is visible to hypervisor, only that could be monitored. Isn't CPU utilization also a part of guest O/S which is invisible to xen hypervisor? Then why is it that only RAM monitoring is excluded?
I think my understanding isn't clear here, could someone help?

Comment: CPU utilization, the hypervisor sees.  Memory utilization from the hypervisor's perspective would likely always be 100% since the VM owns all of its memory whether it's allocated by the VM's kernel or not.  The solution is for a program running inside the instance to push metrics to Cloudwatch, as suggested below.  EBS volumes can't autonomously report free space, for the same reason -- the space is all allocated to you, and EBS can't see how you're using it.

Comment: this page is really useful http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to monitor EC2 RAM with CloudWatch.

This link shows how: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html